# Not retrieving the correct value from a datagridview column

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to retrieve a value from a column within a data grid view (gv_Quals).  I can't seem to find the correct answer online and this is my attempt.  The Unit ID is the second column within the Sql Database.  The row index is passed down.

```
 String txtUnitID =gv_Quals.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].ToString();
```

When I try and run this code, *txtUnitID* will always return this

```
txtUnitID = "System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCellstring"
```

when it should be returning 5 as that is the UnitID.  I'm I doing it wrong or have I forgot something.  Sorry if I seem vague, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is DataBound column in your grid than you can get value using

```
gv_Quals.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Text
```

Or if its any control then you have to first cast that control and then you can get value from that control.

Comment: Thank you its works! Ill accept the answer when the time limit is over :)